# iframe set src value from a php code file without showing path in inspect element

Tags: php, pdf, iframe

I have these code to display pdf using PHP.

So far, I managed to display the pdf in browser. But pdf page load into browser.

Current **Php.file**

```
<?php
    require_once 'connection.php'; 
    $user = new UserData();
    if($user->isLoggedIn())
    { 
        $filename   = base64_decode($_GET['param1']);  
        $directory  = base64_decode($_GET['param2']); 

        $remote_pdf = 'uploads/'.$directory.'/'.$filename.'';
        $remote_file_name = end(explode('/', $remote_pdf));
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'. $remote_file_name .'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        readfile($remote_pdf);   
    }
    else
    {

    } 
?>
```

But my goal is to view the pdf file inside iframe using the php code above. Is it possible to do that ?  I tried to paste the same php code inside iframe src but it didn't working.

Here's what my current code look like.

new **php.file**

```
<?php

    require_once 'connection.php'; 

    $user = new UserData();
    if($user->isLoggedIn())
    { 
        $filename   = base64_decode($_GET['param1']);  
        $directory  = base64_decode($_GET['param2']); 

        include 'templates/header.php';
        ?>              
            <!-- Main content -->
            <section class="content"> 

                <iframe align="center" width="100%" height="100%" src="<?php 

                $remote_pdf = 'uploads/'.$directory.'/'.$filename.'';
                $remote_file_name = end(explode('/', $remote_pdf));
                header('Content-type: application/pdf');
                header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'. $remote_file_name .'"');
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                readfile($remote_pdf); 

                 ?>" frameborder="yes" scrolling="yes" name="myIframe" id="myIframe"></iframe>

            </section>

        <?php
        include 'templates/footer.php';

    }
    else
    {

    } 
?>
```

Appreciate if someone can help me to fix this problem.

Thanks.